# Android App Crash On Button Click

Tags: java, android, xml, button, logcat

I am building an app and on a button click the app crashes. The app was working perfectly about a week ago and the code has not been altered in anyway since the last time I tested it. Now when I click the Login in button it crashes. This makes no sense as it hasn't been edited. Source code below.

**Login.java**

```
package com.example.martin.ivebeenthere;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void onClickbtnFeed(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Feed.class));
    }

}
```

**content_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Login"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="276dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClickbtnFeed"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login With Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="#3b5998"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Feed.java (Page Linked With Button)**

```
package com.example.martin.ivebeenthere;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Feed extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        String[] users = {"\nMartin Hoban\n\nVisited Dublin 2 Hours Ago\n","\nJack White\n\nVisited Mayo 10 Hours Ago\n","\nSarah Cox\n\nVisited Cork 1 Day Ago\n","\nMalcolm Holmes\n\nVisited Knock 2 Days Ago\n", "\nCraig Fisher\n\nVisited The Spire 2 Days Ago\n", "\nHannah Smith\n\nVisited Mayo 3 Days Ago\n"
        ,"\nLanelle Delaune\n\nVisited Limerick 1 Week Ago\n", "\nHanna Whitlow\n\nVisited Paris 1 Week Ago\n", "\nMoses Primm\n\nVisited Italy 3 Weeks Ago\n", "\nBerta Pedraza\n\nVisited The Aillwee Caves 1 Month Ago\n"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 4) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CheckinInfo.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Feed.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Map.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged Out",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Feed.onCreate(Feed.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**activity_feed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_feed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Feed">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_feed" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Rendering Problem In Design View of activity_feed.xml**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1464)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.DrawerLayoutUtil.openDrawer(DrawerLayoutUtil.java:56)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.DrawerLayoutUtil.openDrawer(DrawerLayoutUtil.java:50)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.postInflateProcess(BridgeInflater.java:361)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:968)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:973)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:235)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is line 38? Also post your `activity_feed.xml`.

Comment: Line 38: navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: app_bar_feed.xml posted!

Comment: please view updated question all my other button clicks work this is the only one that does not also there is to many layouts to post the question would become to long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the referenced dimension resource can't be found.

The reason may be, you have dimensions specified for specific screen sizes only.

your content.xml:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

define them in values-820dp/dimens.xml or define them in content.xml
you can remove them too.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `navigationView` is null. That means there's no view with id `nav_view` in your `activity_feed` layout. Make sure to include all views you try to find with `findViewById()` in `onCreate()` into the layout.

Comment: if `nav_view` did not exist it would not come up in the intellisense